# video of someone do/doing something

Tags: gerunds, bare-infinitives

which of the following is grammatically correct?

1. A video of someone doing something.
2. A video of someone do something.

I am fairly sure only the first one is grammatically correct, but I would appreciate an explanation.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different words (verbs, adjectives, prepositions) allow or require different constructions.

A preposition, such as *of*, almost always takes an *-ing* clause, and cannot take other kinds of clause:

> A video **of** somebody doing something.

> They won **by** cheating.

> My purpose **in** calling you here was to explain.

(I've said "almost always", but actually I can't think of any counter-examples. Expressions like "start to do", "intend to do", "try to do" are not counter-examples, because the "to" is not a preposition, but part of the "to-infinitive" that those words "start", "intend" etc require).